Pandas : Re-arranging columns with date year as header
Wish to re-arrange date columns (with Month Year as header) in descending order from left to right. All non-date cols are shifted to extreme left before the date columns begin. If possible as the Column headers are mix-case, so need to process as case-insensitive.
demo = {
'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
'Apr 2022': ['New', 'Los', 'Chic', 'Hous'],
'aPRil 2024': ['York', 'Anges', 'cago', 'ston'],
'Vanilla': ['nfd', 'bdfh', 'tyii', 'liu'],
'aUg 2023': ['NewYork', 'LosAngeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston'],
'deC 2022': ['Neork', 'Logeles', 'Chago', 'Hoston'] }

result = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
    'Vanilla': ['nfd', 'bdfh', 'tyii', 'liu'],
    'aPRil 2024': ['York', 'Anges', 'cago', 'ston'],
    'aUg 2023': ['NewYork', 'LosAngeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston'],
    'deC 2022': ['Neork', 'Logeles', 'Chago', 'Hoston'],
    'Apr 2022': ['New', 'Los', 'Chic', 'Hous'] }


I honestly can't follow anything in this question. I have no idea why the city names just keep becoming more and more unintelligible

You can convert to_datetime with errors='coerce' as key to sort_index. In addition pass ascending=False, na_position='first' as parameters to get the dates in descending order and the non-dates first:
df = pd.DataFrame(demo)

result = df.sort_index(
    axis=1,
    key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce', format='mixed'),
    ascending=False,
    na_position='first',
)

Note depending on the pandas version, it might be needed to first preprocess the string to homogenize the case: key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.title(), errors='coerce').
Output:
      Name  Age Vanilla aPRil 2024    aUg 2023 deC 2022 Apr 2022
0    Alice   25     nfd       York     NewYork    Neork      New
1      Bob   30    bdfh      Anges  LosAngeles  Logeles      Los
2  Charlie   35    tyii       cago     Chicago    Chago     Chic
3    David   40     liu       ston     Houston   Hoston     Hous

This will use the following intermediate to sort the columns:
pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce', format='mixed')

DatetimeIndex(['NaT', 'NaT', '2022-04-01', '2024-04-01', 'NaT', '2023-08-01',
               '2022-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort_index'           modified to # Sort the columns of the DataFrame based on date format
result = df.sort_index(
axis=1,
key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.title(), errors='coerce'),
ascending=False,
na_position='first',
)
print(result)

@Dan Of course I assumed DataFrames: demo = pd.DataFrame(demo). I edited the answer to give it a different name.

revised code is not working for me, refer this line in my comment          key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.title(), errors='coerce'),       is working for me

@Dan which pandas version did you use? This works without title on pandas 2.2.2

pandas Version 2.0.3

@Dan fair enough, I added a note in the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

import pandas as pd
demo = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
    'Apr 2022': ['New', 'Los', 'Chic', 'Hous'],
    'aPRil 2024': ['York', 'Anges', 'cago', 'ston'],
    'Vanilla': ['nfd', 'bdfh', 'tyii', 'liu'],
    'aUg 2023': ['NewYork', 'LosAngeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston'],
    'deC 2022': ['Neork', 'Logeles', 'Chago', 'Hoston']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(demo)
Sort columns
sorted_columns = sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'), reverse=True)

Move non-date columns to the left
date_columns = [col for col in sorted_columns if pd.to_datetime(col, errors='coerce') is not pd.NaT]
non_date_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col not in date_columns]
result = df[non_date_columns + date_columns]

print(result)
output: 

      Name  Age Vanilla aPRil 2024    aUg 2023     deC 2022  Apr 2022
0    Alice   25     nfd      York    NewYork     Neork       New
1      Bob   30    bdfh     Anges  LosAngeles   Logeles       Los
2  Charlie   35     tyii      cago     Chicago     Chago       Chic
3    David   40     liu      ston    Houston     Hoston       Hous

Explanation:
1. Convert Columns to Dates: Columns are sorted based on their parsed
    datetime values. 
 2. Handle Non-Date Columns: Non-date columns are identified and kept on the left. 
 3. Combine and Reorder: Non-date
    columns are placed on the left, and date columns are sorted in
    descending order to the right.


my result  date_columns
Out[44]: ['aPRil 2024', 'Apr 2022', 'aUg 2023', 'deC 2022']
